# ¿Como traer datos de MySql con más de dos rangos de fechas?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Intento hacer lo siguiente:

```
static function offerMetricsGrouped($query)
{

    $fromDate = Carbon::parse(request()->from);
    $toDate = Carbon::parse(request()->to);
    $daysInRange = $fromDate->diffInDays($toDate) + 1;



    return $query->selectRaw('offer_id, local_id')
        ->selectRaw('sum(total_quantity) as total_quantity')
        ->selectRaw('sum(quantity) as quantity')
        ->selectRaw('round(sum(total_sold), 2) as total_sold')
        ->selectRaw('sum(total_orders) as total_orders')
        ->selectRaw('round(sum(total_edc_commission), 2) as total_edc_commission')
        ->selectRaw('round(sum(total_amount_offered), 2) as total_amount_offered')
        ->selectRaw('count(date) as active_days')
        ->selectRaw('(' . $daysInRange . ' - count(date)) as inactive_days')
        ->selectRaw('IF(sum(total_quantity) > 0, round((100*(sum(quantity) / sum(total_quantity))), 2), 0) as sale_ratio')
        ->selectRaw('count(case when precise = 0 then 1 end) as precise')
        ->groupBy(['offer_id', 'local_id']);
}
```

pero quiero incluir un segundo rango de fechas para poder crear un excel de comparativas.
Un ejemplo sencillo quiero mostrar los datos desde 01/11/2021 al 30/11/2021 y también desde 01/12/2021 al 29/12/2022

alguna idea?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#where-clauses) de Laravel, al armar la consulta puedes usar `where`

```
...
->where('fecha', '>', alguna_fecha)
->where('fecha', '<=', otra_fecha)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a lo que indicas puedes probar un **whereBetween**:

```js
$var = DB::table('tabla')
           ->whereBetween('rango1', [fecha1, fecha2])
           ->orWhereBetween('rango2', [fecha2, fecha3])  
->get();
```